# Question on Type command that has >?

Tags: batch-file

```
         type file.txt > file2.txt \\ sends the file.txt contains to file2.txt
```

Suppose if the file name is stored in file2.txt How do i send it to type command? How do i open the file contents of it. If the file name is stored in file2.txt?

```
         type >file2.txt to open it? \\  its not working says incorrect syntax
```

I tried it in many ways.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
type file2.txt
```

Or if you want to combine come commands:

```
find "2011-07" logfile.txt | type
```

Or, if these are not what you want, maybe it is this:

`file2.txt` contains a filename (probably from a previous `dir` command). How can I open that file? – but sadly, I don't know the answer to this question.

Update: try this:

```
for /F %F in (file2.txt) do type %F
```

Comment: `type` must have one argument, the name of the file to display, so your second snippet, the one with `find`, won't work like that.

Comment: Hmmm, too bad. But I found a surrogate: `findstr /R ".*"` is the Windows pendant to UNIX's `cat`.

Comment: Yes, but... why? :) Simply `find "2011-07" logfile.txt`, without any piping, would work just as well.

Comment: Good question. The original question is already answered, but then you pointed out that `type` is not the Windows equivalent of `cat`. So I researched a bit to find that. Anyway, it's getting off-topic here. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "usebackq" %I IN (`type file.txt`) DO set VAR=%I
type %VAR%
```

Comment: if you are able, you may also want to consider using Powershell, it gives you a much better language to work with

Answer (score 2):

In most programming languages there are several ways to do the same things. I always thought that the easier/simpler one is the best one:

```
set /P VAR=< file.txt
type %VAR%
```

Regards...

Antonio